# mysql db table query

Tags: mysql, database-table

i have two tables:

```
users{user_id, username, picture}
likes{id, user_id, image_id}
```

the query im trying to do is:

```
select username, picture
from user and from likes
where user_id=user_id
and image_id=4
```

but i dnt know how to connect them, thanks

Answer (score 3):

The key is to use an INNER [JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) between the two tables.

```
SELECT u.username, u.picture
    FROM user u
        INNER JOIN likes l
            ON u.user_id = l.user_id
    WHERE l.image_id = 4
```